# how to change border color of required input fields?

Tags: css

I'm trying to change browser's default border style for required field which uses box-shadow in firefox and outline in chrome.

So, I'm doing like this:

```
*{
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}
input{
    border: 2px solid black;
}
input:invalid{
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

But this shows red border already on load of the window. But I wanted it to be red only when it's invalid.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5vztkc5z/1/)

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Please note I can't add classes to input fields...

Comment: since u are putting required then it cannot be empty therefore it is invalid when the page loads since it is empty thats why it starts off red and when you put text in it turns black

Answer (score 4):

Since we only want to denote it invalid once it has focus. you could try code like:-

```
input:focus:required:invalid {border: 2px solid red;}
input:required:valid { border: 2px solid black; }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L98wotLc/)

Comment: Yup i have tried...Check the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5vztkc5z/1/) ( JSFIDDLE) in my answer.

Comment: @C-linkNepal Glad i could help u :)

Comment: It works if you focus on the `input`. But if you leave the `input` empty it will turn back to black again. That's the only problem.

Comment: This is not possible until you add some class. JS can solve this issue too if you want to use.

Comment: No, I wanted just with pure css and without adding class.

Comment: Yups, u need to play with JS in that case. onBlur u have to do some stuff.

Comment: @Vivek I'll accept your answer if there's no way to fix this issue just with pure css

Comment: @C-linkNepal Did u get way to fix this with pure CSS ?

Answer (score 1):

Should remove `required` to make your input it is valid or else for required field you can do the following

```
input:invalid {
  background: hsla(0, 90%, 70%, 1);
}
input:valid {
  background: hsla(100, 90%, 70%, 1);
}
input:focus {
  background: hsla(100, 90%, 70%, 1);
}
input:required {
  border-color: #800000;
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5vztkc5z/5/)

[**RESOURCE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid)

Comment: You have one more option you can do `input{border: 2px solid black !important;}`

Comment: I have `focus` to your fiddle check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without color:

```
input:required {
    border-color: #ccc !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}
```