# how to make an element that is required (in html) not appear required (in css)

Tags: html, css

So I would like to make HTML element which is required (red in color) have the appearance of a non-required element (gray in color) until a submit button is pushed. Once the submit button is pushed, it should appear as a required element.

Hopefully, this is not vague.

Let me try to explain better what I am after. What I have right now is the required input fields being the color peach all the time, because of the required effect. What I would like to accomplish is the peach color to only appear on the required input elements when the submit button is pushed.

So basically, how do I change the input's outline during different phases of being valid and invalid? Would I need to use javascript for this or is there a simpler solution? pleeeeeaseeeee help meeeeeee....this is driving me crazy.

```css
.form_text_input
{

  display: inline-flex;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 11pt;

}

.form_text_input:required:invalid
{

  outline-width: 1px;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: #ffbda6;

}
```

```html
<label class = "form_text_label">
      First Name: 
    </label>
    <input class = "form_text_input" type = "text" placeholder = "Your first   name...">
    <label class = "form_text_label">
     Last Name: * 
    </label>
    <input class = "form_text_input" type = "text" placeholder = "Your last name..." required>
    <label class = "form_text_label">
    Message: *
    </label>
    <textarea class = "form_text_input" placeholder = "Your message here..." required></textarea>
    <button class = "form_text_submit" type = "submit">
     Send &#9656;
    </button>
```

If looking at the code I want the required input element of "message" or "last name" to appear as the "first name" input element until the submit button is pushed.

Thank you so much for your help and I apologize if this is a silly question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change border color of required input fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425506/how-to-change-border-color-of-required-input-fields)

Answer (score 0):

The `:required` pseudo class selector allows to select element with the required attribute.

So, just remove the `.form_text_input:required:invalid` part from your CSS:

```css
.form_text_input
{
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 95%;
    padding: 8px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 11pt;
}
/* REMOVE THIS PART
.form_text_input:required:invalid
{
    outline-width: 1px;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: #ffbda6;
}*/
```

```html
<label class = "form_text_label">First Name:</label>
<input class = "form_text_input" type = "text" placeholder = "Your first   name...">
<label class = "form_text_label">Last Name: *</label>
<input class = "form_text_input" type = "text" placeholder = "Your last name..." required>
<label class = "form_text_label">Message: *</label>
<textarea class = "form_text_input" placeholder = "Your message here..." required></textarea>
<button class = "form_text_submit" type = "submit">Send &#9656;</button>
```